# URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s

Tags: facebook

Good morning everyone,

For a few days I have been failing to log in with facebook on my website made with WordPress.

The error message I get is the following:

"URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs."

I have tried creating a new Facebook login app and get exactly the same error window.

Can someone please try what is the problem?

[encontinuo.com/login](https://encontinuo.com/login/)

I attach the screenshots with the error and the URI configuration that I have applied in the Facebook login app.

Thank you very much.

[Facebook connect button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weWxy.png)

[URIs error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMwqG.png)

[URIs config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WAKl.png)

Comment: Your login dialog call uses the `redirect_uri` value `https://encontinuo.com/login/?provider=facebook`, but all the URLs you have configured are for the `www` subdomain.

Comment: I created a new Facebook Login app and included the www subdomain and it works.

Thanks CBroe!